# How to label the leaves of a dendrogram in hclust in R using categorical variables from another column in the same dataframe

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I would like to change the default labels for the leaves of a dendrogram to match a categorical variable column in a dataframe generated using `dplyr` `group_by` and `summarise` functions. This is a screenshot of the dataframe.
[image: dataframe]
I would like to use the 'm' column variables as the labels for the dendrogram.

This is the code to generate the dendrogram (`sfdf_lop` is the dataframe)

```
csfdf_lop <- hclust(dist(sfdf_lop[, -1]), method = "complete")
plot(csfdf_lop)
```

and the output looks like this:
[image: dendrogram]

How do I use the variables in the column 'm' to label the leaves, in place of the default numbered leaves?

**Edit** Below is the result of using the suggested code

```
tempdf<- as.data.frame(sfdf_lop)
row.names(tempdf)<- tempdf$m
csfdf_lop <- hclust(dist(tempdf[, -1]), method = "complete")
plot(csfdf_lop)
```

[image: dendrogram]

Comment: @Dave2e This definitely adds the correct labels, but most of the dendrogram is missing and what there is left of it is inverted. Moreover the leaves themselves are not labelled. No space here to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your data to data.frame and define the row.names to equal column M.

```
tempdf<- as.data.frame(sfdf_lop)
row.names(tempdf)<- tempdf$m

csfdf_lop <- hclust(dist(tempdf[, -1]), method = "complete")
plot(csfdf_lop)
```

[image]

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the original question. As you can see the output is not as expected, even though the default labels have now been replaced with the sub-cellular location labels.

Comment: comment above. Many thanks.